# Nth percentile in python is different from Dynatrace result

Tags: python, excel, numpy, percentile, dynatrace

I am trying to create a report based on the data extracted from Dynatrace.

I am extracting the data on daily basis for the events, in my Python Django report, I need to show the Nth percentile data (like *30*th percentile, *60*th Percentile, *75*th Percentile, *90*th Percentile).

When I try to pull the data from Dynatrace the below list is the result:
`[1563,2731,3586,3966,4174,4971,6055,9175,15667]`

For this list, when I use numpy.percentile or df.quantile, I am getting one value which is similar to the percentile value like the formula I used in Excel
However the Dynatrace PERCENTILE function is showing a different value all together

For example, From the excel and Python, I am getting 75th Percentile as - **6055**
From Dynatrace I am getting - **6835**

I tried to use some online tools to calculate the Percentile but all seems to be giving 6055.
If someone can explain this how **DynaTrace** is calculating this formula that would be a great help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of discrepancies are normally due to the [interpolation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#The_linear_interpolation_between_closest_ranks_method), very noticeable when the sample is very small.

However, 6055 is exactly percentile 75 in your sample:

```
1563   2731   3586   3966   4174   4971   6055   9175  15667
 0/8    1/8    2/8    3/8    4/8    5/8    6/8    7/8    8/8
   0  0.125   0.25  0.375    0.5  0.625   0.75  0.875      1
```

Accordingly, Numpy produces the same result using any of its [interpolation methods](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) (linear, lower, higher, nearest, midpoint).

Dynatrace may be using a more complex interpolation method like [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.04023). One of the authors is affiliated to Dynatrace.